# Is XML's root closing tag mandatory?

Tags: xml, standards, w3c

I serialized an object in Java, and I got the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_92" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
  <object class="...." id="SmartLayout0">
  <!-- ... -->
  </object>
```

As you see, the root tag `<java>` is not closed.

Is it legal in XML to not close this root tag? Does the XML standard explicitly allow such shortcut?

Comment: It's not legal.  If you're using XMLEncoder, I suspect you forgot to call XMLEncoder.close(), which I assume will generate the closing tag.

Comment: @Joe You got it right, a missing `close()` was the issue, but since the parser was OK with such XML, I wasn't sure whether closing tag is fully mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unlike in the non-XHTML versions of HTML, all tags in XML must be closed or be self-closing.

All [elements in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-element) must be either self-closing or must consist of matching opening and closing tags:

```
element ::= EmptyElemTag | STag content ETag
```